# Загрузка файла на сервер

Tags: javascript

Использую такой код для загрузки изображений на сервер:

```
<input id="avatar" type="file">
<div onClick="run_image()">Загрузить аватар</div>

function run_image() {
        var file = document.querySelector("#avatar").files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);


        var XHR = "onload" in new XMLHttpRequest() ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
        var xhr = new XHR();

        xhr.open('POST', 'pages/edit/avatar.php', true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState !== 4) {
                return;
            }
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                document.getElementById('window_data').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

В файле avatar.php содержится js код меняющий стили некоторых елементов, который не срабатывает, как делать что бы срабатывал js код?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что присвоение HTML не выполняет  блоки. Самый просто вариант - отвечать JS кодом без  тегов и тому подобного, и выполнять код через eval().

Еще как вариант - использовать jQuery, или же написать тоже самое что делает он вручную. jQuery фактически выполняет всё  теги сам, если они есть, при вызове element.html().

Более подробно здесь ( на Англ. языке ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Так же уже готовый ответ как выполнять script теги:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2592092/executing-script-elements-inserted-with-innerhtml